# Unable to download at this time; enterprise build/ad hoc distribution

Tags: xcode, code-signing

So I have a very weird problem. Trying to deploy the once click deployment using the enterprise code signing thing.

I have it uploaded on the server and I go to the link in safari, when I open it on the iPhone it gives me unable to download, application cannot be installed at this time. However, when I tried it on my iPad (iPhone app running on iPad), it works just fine. Why is this?

Comment: is your device in the adhoc provisioning profile?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is one of 2 things.

The xml in your .plist that goes with the app has incorrect values or you are using a non enterprise distribution certificate. Make sure you have a current certificate and when building select that cert. Also make sure the xml in your plist is correct.

Note a fields you enter when building the app ( icon, target host, etc. ) are not necessary to enter all the time. ( I just type the letter a into each field ) I copied the original plist and changed the values manually. I deploy the file to a temp folder and only copy the .ipa to by IIS virtual folder.